# Is there a website that can plot vectorial functions?

Tags: graphing-functions

I know Desmos can plot some things, not nearly as elegantly as Wolfram Alpha, but for vectorial functions I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://anvaka.github.io/fieldplay/, and it's fairly easy to use. You could also make a custom one with Python `matplotlib.quiver()`.